# What does each cheat do in Guitar Hero: World Tour?

Tags: guitar-hero-world-tour

I can easily find a list of cheats for *Guitar Hero: World Tour* by just searching the web. However, even after unlocking so many cheats, I still don't know what they do.

Some cheats are quite descriptive (the one that unlocks quickplay songs, or the auto-kick one), but others are not that obvious (Extra Line 6 Tones).

Can someone please put a list with all cheats and the descriptions of what they do?

*(if that matters, it is the PlayStation 3 version of the game)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Guitar Hero wiki has an [excellent summary](http://guitarhero.wikia.com/wiki/Cheat_Codes#Guitar_Hero_World_Tour) of cheats in GH:WT. I'll summarize the cheats below, but I would recommend checking out their wiki for more details.

#### Available Choices

- Aaron Steele!, Jonny Viper!, Nick!, Rina! - unlocks the hidden characters.
- AT&T Park - Unlocks AT&T Park as a venue.
- Quickplay Songs - Unlocks all songs for Quickplay.

#### Appearance

- Air Instruments, Invisible Rocker - Hides instruments or band members, respectively. (You can't use both cheats at the same time.)
- Flame Color, Gem Color, Star Color, Vocal Fireball - Changes the color of the flames, notes and fret bar, notes in Star Power, and vocals' "comet", respectively.

#### Gameplay

- Always Slide - All notes, except for chords and open notes, can be played on the slider bar. (Guitar and bass only, of course.)
- Auto Kick - Kick notes will be played for you; you don't have to use the pedal.
- HyperSpeed - Unlocks HyperSpeed cheats for guitar, bass, and drums.
- Performance Mode - Hides everything but the stage; you'll have to play notes from memory.

#### Music Studio

- Extra Line 6 Tones - Extra guitar effects are available in the Music Studio. Line 6 does real-life amps and effects, and they licensed [full amp and cab modeling](http://xbox360.ign.com/articles/882/882888p3.html) for GH:WT, so unlocking this cheat makes those effects available to you.

Comment: What 'extra guitar effects'?

Comment: I'll update that part of the answer to specify.

Answer (score 0):

The gem colors took me awhile to find out but it changes the color of the notes in the game...such as toxic waste, eggs and bacon and other cool ones.